# Spark fails with java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded?

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark-sql

This is my java code in which I am querying data from Hive using Apache spark sql.

```
JavaSparkContext ctx = new JavaSparkContext(new SparkConf().setAppName("LoadData").setMaster("MasterUrl"));
HiveContext sqlContext = new HiveContext(ctx.sc());
List<Row> result = sqlContext.sql("Select * from Tablename").collectAsList();
```

when I run this code it throws java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded. How to solve this or how to increase the memory in Spark configuration.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `spark-shell` to run it then you can use the `driver-memory` to bump the memory limit:

`spark-shell --driver-memory Xg [other options]`

If the executors are having problems then you can adjust their memory limits with `--executor-memory XG`

You can find more info how to exactly set them in the guides: [submission](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html) for executor memory, [configuration](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html) for driver memory.

@Edit: since you are running it from Netbeans you should be able to pass them as JVM arguments `-Dspark.driver.memory=XG` and `-Dspark.executor.memory=XG`. I think it was in `Project Properties` under `Run`.

Comment: But I am running it as a Java application. In that scenario how to do that

Comment: @wazza aren't you building a jar and submitting it to spark?

Comment: No I am running the above code directly in netbeans itself

Comment: @wazza you can try adding the parameters from my edit

Comment: I am getting the same exception. The table contains 1 million rows and is there any other way to query that without this memory problems

Comment: @wazza have you tried building a jar and submitting it into spark? Not from netbeans (with the same memory options as I posted above). Also you can try setting `-Xmx` in your run configuration to a higher value. Also do you really need the `collectAsList`?

Comment: As I am creating a web service and as of now I am using for loop for getting the values from the result set. So I have used collectasList to collect the result and trying to convert it to string

Comment: Is there any other effective steps to achieve this?

Comment: @wazza how big are your tables? do you need the whole object? or could you, instead of returning `*` return only some fields? otherwise I guess you will have to chunk this into smaller queries using offset/limit

Comment: This table contains about 10 million entries and I want to return the entire rows when queried. For this scenario what to use for effective performance and avoiding memory problems

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85409/discussion-between-wazza-and-mateusz-dymczyk).

Comment: @wazza, Were you able to run this same piece of code from java editor? I am trying to run it in eclipse, getting the same issue. Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

have you found any solutions for your issue yet?
please share them if you have :D

and here is my idea: rdd and also javaRDD has a method `toLocalIterator()`,
spark document said that

> The iterator will consume as much memory as the largest partition in
>   this RDD.

it means iterator will consume less memory than List if the rdd is devided into many partitions, you can try like this:

```
Iterator<Row> iter = sqlContext.sql("Select * from Tablename").javaRDD().toLocalIterator();
while (iter.hasNext()){
    Row row = iter.next();
    //your code here
}
```

ps: it's just an idea and i haven't tested it yet